# Maximum Average Subarray I, Leetcode. Time Limit Exceeded

Tags: arrays, max, average, sub-array

This question is from leetcode. My output is correct and 123 / 123 test cases passed, but took too long. Can you help me to improve the same code I have?

Question:
Given an array consisting of n integers, find the contiguous subarray of given length k that has the maximum average value. And you need to output the maximum average value.

Example 1:

Input: [1,12,-5,-6,50,3], k = 4
Output: 12.75
Explanation: Maximum average is (12-5-6+50)/4 = 51/4 = 12.75

```
class Solution {
    public double findMaxAverage(int[] nums, int k) {
     
        
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        double max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        while(i+k <= nums.length){ 
             
         double sum = 0;
            while(i < k + j){ 
             sum += nums[i]; 
                i++;
                }    
            max = Math.max(max, sum);
            j++;
            i = j;
        }
        
        return max/k;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- I guess maybe it would get stuck to one of the `while`s.
- We can solve the problem `O(N)`:

```
public class Solution {
    public static final double findMaxAverage(
        final int[] nums,
        final int k
    ) {
        long currSum = 0;

        for (int index = 0; index < k; index++) {
            currSum += nums[index];
        }

        long maxSum = currSum;

        for (int index = k; index < nums.length; index++) {
            currSum += nums[index] - nums[index - k];
            maxSum = Math.max(maxSum, currSum);
        }

        return (double) maxSum / k;

    }
}
```